# Blowing into the wide end of the shofar

Tags: halacha, shofar

Assuming my lungs were sufficiently powerful, could I blow the shofar for a mitzva if I blew into the wide end?

Related: [Inhaling prayers?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22440/inhaling-prayers)

Comment: מן המצר קראתי יה ענני במרחב יה

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch OC 586:12

> והוא הדין אם תקע במקום הרחב, פסול (ר"ן פרק ב' דראש השנה).‏

It's invalid.