# Volume of "Barukh Shem Kevod", Relative to "Shema Yisrael"

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shema, loud-quiet

When reciting the Shema, the prevalent custom is to say the first line ("shema yisrael... echad") out loud, and the following line ("barukh shem kevod...") in a whisper. This custom can be sourced in Pesachim 56a, and is also mentioned by the Rambam (Hilkhos Qeriyas Shema 1:4) and the Shulchan Arukh (Orach Chayim 61:13).

In the event that one needs to whisper the first line as well (for example, if there is a sleeping baby in the room), is it sufficient that the second line be whispered as well or does it specifically need to be said *more* quietly than the first line?

Comment: `does it specifically need to be said more quietly than the first line` Do you have any reason to suspect that it has to be quieter? Do any of the sources you cite imply this?

Comment: In a whisper or quietly? Cf https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14478